# How to properly centre vector arrows upon characters

Tags: math-mode, symbols, arrows, characters, vector

I'm using the standard LaTeX vector arrows in math mode, but they are always aligned in such a way that they result shifted if they haven't an italic character underneath.

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}

\begin{document}
$\vec{A}\ \vv{A}\ \vec{\mathrm{A}}\ \vv{\mathrm{A}}\ \vv{\ell}\ \vec{\ell}$
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

I've compared the traditional arrows with the ones from the esvect package because I'd love to have the centring of the esvect arrows upon non-italic characters but maintain the normal arrow type and length of the plain LaTeX arrow.

This type of centring should only apply to non-italic characters, but it would be nice to be able, if needed, to manually adjust the centring of the vector arrow above any character too.

Thank you for your time, it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a macro with some horizontal kerning adjustment.

In the following MWE `\myvec` has an optional argument (default value 1mu) to indicate that adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}
\newcommand{\myvec}[2][1mu]{\vec{#2\mkern-#1}\mkern#1}
\begin{document}
Benchmark:

$\vec{A}\ \vv{A}\ \vec{\mathrm{A}}\ \vv{\mathrm{A}}\ \vv{\ell}\ \vec{\ell}$

With my macro:

$\myvec{A}\ \myvec{\ell}$

In case you need to adjust the kerning:


$\myvec[2mu]{A}\ \myvec[2mu]{\ell}$
\end{document}
```

[image]