# What do \vec{\mkern0mu x} and \vec{{} x} mean?

Tags: math-mode, kerning, vector

In the following posts and many other besides [[0]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114321) [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460241), I've seen people use `\vec{\mkern0mu x}`, `\vec{{} x}`, and variants thereof to adjust the vector arrow's kerning.

How do these work? What's the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\vec` is defined as a "math accent", just like `\hat` and others. A math accent placed on a single character will have its position adjusted horizontally to sit over the visual top-center of the character. The amount of adjustment or "skew" is encoded in the kerning information of the font that `x` comes from as a kern between the character (`x` in the question) and another character identified by `\skewchar`. (If the `\skewchar` for the font is high above the baseline, like an accent character, then the kerns will be useful for ordinary typesetting also.)

A math accent placed over a composite math object is not adjusted horizontally. That is the point of the invisible bits used in the question -- converting a single character to a combined math list. Try the tests with the letter `f` for a clearer demonstration of the difference.

The accents and amsmath packages have definitions that attempt to adjust the positioning even over composite arguments.

Aside: `\vec{\/x}` is identical to `\vec{\kern0pt x}` but is quicker to type.

---

And another aside that probably provides too much detail . . .

The italic letter `f` in math has a lot of slope, so there is a big difference between `\vec{f}` and `\vec{\/f}`.  To my eye, with the computer modern math italic fonts, the unskewed `\vec{\/f}` is clearly bad, but the automatically-adjusted `\vec{f}` is excessively skewed.

There is a plain-TeX macro `\skew`, which is inherited by LaTeX, that provides manual adjustment, replacing the automatic positioning based on kerning values:

> \skew ⟨mu-factor⟩ ⟨accent⟩ ⟨symbol(s)⟩

The ⟨mu-factor⟩ gives the adjustment in terms of math units (mu, like the `\mkern0mu` in the question). A value of 3 or 4 looks right to me for *f*. This looks like

```
$\vec{f} - \vec{\/f} = \skew{3.5}\vec{f}$
```

[image: Three f vectors]

You wouldn't want to be typing `\skew`commands before all your math accents, but for particular cases you may want to define new abbreviations like

```
\newcommand\vecf{\skew{3.5}\vec{f}}
```

if that is important notation in your work, and you are responsible for good presentation (as opposed to submitting to a journal where it will be re-typeset).

Note that `\hat{f}` looks great with its automatic positioning.

Comment: If no better answer pops up this week, I'll accept this. I still have one question though: What's a combined math list?

Comment: Ah! That's not any official terminology. Well, "math list" is, referring to a whole section of math or a portion inside `{ }`. I was just trying to say that the argument (a math list) becomes *not* a single character, but a combination of multiple things (defeating the skew adjustment).