# Vector arrow over b is bad when closing parenthesis

Tags: brackets, vector

I've noticed that a vector arrow over the letter b is always very bad looking when b is followed by a closing parenthesis. It looks that this is a unavoidable uglyness... someone got some clue about how to avoid that? In the MWE you can see that in both () and \left( \right) the aesthetics is ruined no matter what...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$
(\vec{b})\qquad\left(\vec{b}\right)
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]
In example: `\((\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\)` it is horrible! And if the letter is a "d" the result is worse.

Comment: I suggest `\vec{b}\,)`

Comment: note article doesn't have a `14pt` option, so this is 10pt, and `$$` should not be used in latex.  I would use the first form, or possibly add a `\,` before `)`

Comment: Thanx both! I took out the [14pt] in the example since it is totally irrelevant. I think this has something to do with the encoding itself and for sure the notorious solution of adding a space is not really elegant (but still somehow hels).

Comment: There's an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460241/411) that may help with centering the vector arrow, especially over d's.